# redireccion muchas veces login middleware laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, blade

estoy haciendo un login propio, sin ocupar lo de artisan
este dice La página

> localhost se ha redirigido demasiadas veces.

**vista**

```
   <form action="{{route('USUPASS')}}" method="get">
 
    @csrf
       <label for="email"> email </label>
       <input class="form-control" 
       type="email"
        name="email"
        placeholder="ingresa tu email">
        {!! $errors->first('email','<span class"help- 
        block">:message</span>')!!}

        <label for="password"> password </label>
        <input class="form-control"
         type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="ingresa tu password">
          {!! $errors->first('password','<span class"help- 
          block">:message</span>')!!}
 
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
       type="submit"> 
      acceder</button>
</form>
```

**controlador**

```
   public function login(){
   $creden = $this->validate(request(),[
  'email'=>'email|required|string',
   'password'=>'password|string'
     ]);
   if( Auth::attempt($creden))
       {
     return "tu sesion ha iniciado correctamente";    
     }
    return "tu sesion ha fallado";   
            }
```

Comment: seria mejor si dieras mas detalles a cerca del error