# laravel 8 problema validate

Tags: laravel, blade

Tengo una vista de login con un formulario con `method="POST"`, `action="{{route('USUPASS')}}"` y dos inputs llamados `email` y `pass`.

Hago la validación de request en el Controlador y me dice:

> localhost se ha redireccionado muchas veces

Es un proyecto nuevo.

**VISTA**

```
<form action="{{route('USUPASS')}}" method="POST" >

    @csrf
    @if($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li> {{$error}}</li>
        @endforeach
        </ul>   
        </div>    
    @endif

    @error('email')
        <small>*{{$message}}
    @enderror

    @error('pass')
        <small>*{{$message}}
    @enderror   

    <input
    type="email"
    name="email"
    placeholder="email"
    class="form-control"
    value="{{old('email')}}">

    < input
    type="password"
    name="pass"
    placeholder="password"
    class="form-control"
    value="{{old('pass')}}">

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"> acceder</button>

</form>
```

**Controlador**

```
public function inicio()
{ 
    return view ('welcome'); 
}

public function post()
{ 
    return view('postlogin');     
}

public function log(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string' 
    ]);
}
```

**Rutas**

```
Route::get('/','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@inicio');
```

Route::post('/login','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@log')->name('USUPASS');
Route::get('/login','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@login')->name('USUPASS');
Route::get('/postlogin','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@post')->name('post');

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato, empezando por la ortografía, la gramática y la puntuación. Realmente no se entiende lo que escribes. Lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. y  [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que el código que muestras sirva a que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Editado, gracias

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si quitas esa validación?

Comment: funciona con normalidad

Comment: voy a necesita mas información sobre todo el formulario, y veo que tiene muchos errores

Comment: Cuando la validación falla durante una solicitud HTTP tradicional, se generará una respuesta de redireccionamiento a la URL anterior. Entonces ¿cuál es la URL anterior?¿Que tienen que ver con el problema todas esas rutas que pones en la pregunta y por qué todas apuntan a la misma función del mismo controlador, incluso siendo algunas get y otra post?¿Que más tienes en esa función? porque dices que si quitas la validación "funciona con normalidad", pero ¿qué significa eso si no hay nada más en la función?¿que funcione con normalidad significa que no hace nada?

Comment: voy a editar mi pregunta

Comment: editado el codigo

Comment: ¿Que pasa si quitas esta ruta `Route::get('/login','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@log')->name('USUPASS');`?

Comment: Puedes eliminar los 2 duplicados que pusistes? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434527 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434988 parece como spam

Answer (score 0):

Usted tiene un error en el código, la variable $request se deber eliminar en su código de valídate, asi es la forma correcta y en el campo input no se le olvide el campo
en caso de verificar si le esta enviado los datos utilizar la función var_var_dump($request);
exit();

para saber si le esta enviado los datos

```
<input type="text" name="email">
```

backend

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;




public function log(Request $request){

        //var_dump($request);
        //exit();
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
}
```

en el archivo web.php deber cambiar

```
Route::get('/login','App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController@log')->name('login');
```

por en la ruta de tu proyecto  App\Http\Controllers\EjemploController.php
no es necesario utilizar la ruta completa
si esta utilizado un formulario tipo post o get en web.php lo tiene que definir el tipo de método en este caso se utilizar el post

```
   Route::post('login','EjemploController@log')->name('login');
   Route::get('login','EjemploController@log')->name('login');
```

Comment: Lo puse pero sigue el error

Comment: La que propones aquí es basado en [\Illuminate\Http\Request](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_validate), sin embargo el método del OP es también válido, a través del trait [ValidatesRequests](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html#method_validate) que se usa en [Controller](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/471195d743de883af0c239c46553da89179824b5/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php#L12).

Comment: Lo de las rutas tampoco es como lo dices [En Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing), la clase RouteServiceProvider contiene una propiedad `$namespace` que se establece en `null` de forma predeterminada. Por lo que si no declaras el controlador con la *standard PHP callable syntax*, deberás poner todo el namespace.